# irrationality of a decimal expansion

Tags: irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Consider the real number in $(0,1)$ having the decimal expansion $${\alpha} = 0.{a_1}{a_2}{a_3}\cdots $$ where $a_j$ is obtained by adding up the digits in the decimal expansion of the positive integer $j$, and then reducing the sum $({\rm mod}\ 10).$ Thus, we can write the first few entries in the decimal expansion as follows: $$0.123456789123456789023456789\cdots$$
Prove that $\alpha$ is an irrational number.

Comment: "$\sigma(k) = -1+(a_{j_0} +1)+\cdots +{a_{m-1}}$" I don't see where you get that at all (or the next formula). It also is not clear what $\cdots$ represents, as the preceeding and succeeding elements do not fit the same pattern. $$\sigma(k) = 9 j_0 + a_{j_0} + \cdots + a_{m-1}$$ How does that reduce to your formula? Even if you work $\mod 10$, you would end up with $-j_0 + a_{j_0} + \cdots + a_{m-1}$.

Comment: I will attempt to clarify and hopefully succeed! I realized that the argument for 9 holds for any digit between 0 and 9. I will edit the post and post a solution. This is the Thue-Morse sequence if we work in base 2 as opposed to base 10 I think. I have deleted my attempted answer and will post a solution when I have thought it through.

Comment: Rational means that the expansion is periodic from some point on. This follows from division algorithm.

Comment: $\sigma(2,999,999,999) = 83 \equiv 3 \mod 10$ and $\sigma(3,000,000,000) = 3$. Any digits can repeat, though the interval between such pairs of repeating digits does indeed grow, as it only happens between $n \times 10^m -1$ and $n \times 10^n$ for any $n > 0$, and $m \equiv 9 \mod 10$.

Comment: "Rational means that the expansion is periodic from some point on. This follows from division algorithm." - Now go teach your grandma to suck eggs!

Comment: Paul-you nailed it. This is exactly what I had in mind. You should post it as a solution!

Comment: Sorry - That is a rather antequated American idiom meaning "you are trying to teach me something you should have realized I already knew". As I am a rather antequated American, I am somewhat given to such idioms. I admit, though, that if you weren't already aware of it, it does sound rather rude. It was intended to be humorous instead.

Comment: As for the rest, while I don't follow your original argument, it was pretty quickly obvious what you were aiming for: final digits other than $9$ increase $\sigma(k)$ by $1$ when you add $1$ to $k$. And final digits of $9$ only give repeat digits under the condition mentioned. So I would consider it your work (especially as I didn't provide a derivation). I was working on it before your two replies, so in fact it repeats something you already said in your first comment.

Comment: Please don't apologize Paul-I got it-anyway it wasn't directed at me-and even if it was no worries at all!! But we worked on it together, and your idea was on point-so I wanted to ensure you got credit!

Comment: This is proving to be a tough nut to crack!! I was ble to prove that no digit can appear more than twice in this decimal expansion-but the irrationality proof is still eluding me.